# How to find lists of favorite for each tweet?

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I want to collect the list of favorite(like) in each tweet for a specific celebrity so that I can get the top three users who like his/her posts the most in a period. However, I can't find any information using Tweepy(Twitter API) to gather it.   Is it the only possible to use Selenium to collect the favorite list for each tweet?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter's API does not provide this information. Also note that using Selenium or other web scraping methods is against the Twitter Terms of Service.